# How to pass image entry in atom rss feed. in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rss, ruby-on-rails-3.1

every time people give tutorials on how to make atom rss templates, but my question here is how can i pass in and image in the rss format. for instance i have this code sample in rss

```
atom_feed :language => 'en-US' do |feed|
  feed.title @title
  feed.updated @updated

  @news_items.each do |item|
    next if item.updated_at.blank?

    feed.entry( item ) do |entry|
      entry.url news_item_url(item)
      entry.title item.title
      entry.content item.content, :type => 'html'

      # the strftime is needed to work with Google Reader.
      entry.updated(item.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")) 

      entry.author do |author|
        author.name entry.author_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

where can i display the image of the article and how do i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atom format (http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/) supports an icon (square) and a logo (rectangular)... so in your block

```
entry.icon '/path/to/my/icon.png'
entry.logo '/path/to/my/logo.png'
```

---

EDIT: serves me right for not checking some code. Those elements are optional elements for the `feed` element, not the `entry`. Try:

```
feed.icon '/path/to/my/icon.png'
```

Comment: i did this in my block but the image is not being displayed `entry.icon image_tag story.image(:small)`

Comment: Don't use `image_tag`. This will create an HTML image tag. You need the `image_path` helper, and prepend it with your domain name.